# Probability Distribution Notation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation

It's been a while since I've dabbled in probability, so I'm just catching myself up on notation again. Currently, I'm working through Karlin and Taylor's *A First Course in Stochastic Processes* and am looking at question 2 in Elementary Problems.

The problem asks for a probability distribution of a **discrete** random variable $X$, then gives a solution stating $p(k) = \dots$.

My question is, does $p(k)$ mean $p(X = k)$ or $p(X \leq k)$? Based on my solution, I'm leaning towards the former, and assume this is due to the fact that $X$ is a **discrete** r.v. as opposed to a continuous (in which case a $p(X = k) = 0$). Is there a distinction between probability densities and distributions, and what notation $p(k)$ means in each case?

Comment: Does the author define the notation elsewhere in the text?  If not, it would help to reproduce the problem/solution statements, which should reveal whether it represents a [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) or [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

Comment: Discrete random variables are always specified by the probability mass function / counting measure density

Comment: As opposed to a CDF? So it is safe to assume that when they say distribution for a discrete r.v. they are referring to the mass function?

Comment: @AndrewZhang A CDF would completely characterize the distribution as well

Comment: @Golden_Ratio yes, but no one does this.